# C++: use string& and unique_ptr<SomeClass>& for map<string, unique_ptr<SomeClass>>

Tags: c++

I have following string& and unique_ptr&

```
const FilePath& path; // given as parameter
auto key = path.BaseName().value();

auto value = make_unique<SomeClass>();
```

I would like to use these in the following map

```
map<string, unique_ptr<SomeClass>> myMap;
```

When I do the following,

```
myMap.emplace(key, value);
```

I get this error:

```
note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<SomeClass>>::emplace<const std::string &, std::unique_ptr<SomeClass> &>' requested here
```

I think this means that I am trying to put string& and unique_ptr& where string and unique_ptr is needed.

Would there be a way to use &-variable to a non-&-parameter?

Full code:

```
map<string, unique_ptr<SomeClass>> myMap;

void function (const FilePath& path) {
  auto key = path.BaseName().value();
  auto value = make_unique<SomeClass>();
  myMap.emplace(key, value);
}
```

Comment: There's more to the error than that. Consider updating that and adding enough code to make this a [mcve].

Comment: Your code does produce an error, but what you are calling an error in this question is clearly labeled as a "note".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) can't be copied, but only moved. You can use [`std::move`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) to convert `value` to rvalue:

```
myMap.emplace(key, std::move(value));
```

Comment: I see. I will try that. Thanks! How about trying to put string& to string parameter?

Comment: Actually std::move fixes the error completely. Thanks a lot! Regarding string&, doesnt the error message above indicates that the key is string& ?

Comment: @wWw `emplace` takes by-reference, passing `key` is fine, it could be bound to the reference parameter.

Comment: Awesome Thank you very much for explanation!

Answer (score -1):

In this case you don't even need to use std::unique_ptr!
Your map will own the instances of MyClass anyway. So why not
make a map of SomeClass directly?

Don't dynamically allocate memory yourself unless you really have to.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem> // <== STL has its own filesystem 
#include <map>
#include <string>

// do not use : using namespace std; !

class SomeClass
{
public:
    explicit SomeClass(const int, const int ) {}
};

std::map<std::string_view, SomeClass> myMap;

void function(const std::filesystem::path& path) 
{
    auto key = path.filename(); 
    myMap.emplace( key, 1, 2 ); // 1,2 are the parameters for constructor of SomeClass
}
```